# Reliable auto logout after an hour

Tags: php, automation, logout

I have some javascript that is supposed to log you out after an hour but it has some problems, first of all, it doesn't logout you out after an hour, its normally about 20 minutes, and secondly it doesn't always work 100% of the time, say I leave my PC on overnight sometimes I am still logged in (maybe not in the PHP session) and on the same page.

I have a feeling if the screen turns off it pauses the javascript counter.

The code is:

```
var delay = 3600000;
setTimeout(function(){ window.location =  base_url + 'user/logout' }, delay);
```

Is there a better more reliable way of doing this? How is it done on banking sites?

**EDIT:** I don't mean this will actually log out the user, of course that is done server side, I just want the page to automatically redirect to the login page after an hour, just like the banks say "You have been logged out due to inactivity".

This is because there will be sensitive data that I don't want being left on someone's screen overnight

Comment: Can't you define a session timeout of one hour on the server side?

Comment: This script I wrote will logout inactive users: http://phpsnips.com/snip-39#.UaYUJbVwok0

Comment: The session does terminate, IE, if you went to another page you would get taken back to the login page, but these pages have sensitive information on them so I didn't want someone to accidentally leave the page open

Comment: the automatic logout shuldnt be client-side. You should check it on the server-side every time the user does an pageload. Check if 1. have a valid session, 2. when happens the last pageload before this pageload.

Comment: I have used the jquery plug-in idletimeout and it works great for idle screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach focus and blur event handlers on the window object to track if the window gets or loses focus.

Also, it's bad idea to logout user after timeout (there can be user activity, ajax requests). Better to check that session is alive at server-side by ajax request and only when it's expired, delete document content and show popup with message about session expiration.

Comment: Note: server-side action that checks session status must not prolong session lifetime!